# Can't connect to mobile device

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, windows-vista, mobile

I've been developing an application for a second generation Workabout Pro from PSION Teklogix.

Recently my company underwent an upgrade re: operating systems and Visual Studio versions, so I'm stuck with Windows Vista (and Visual Studio 2008).

I've connected the same Workabout Pro unit I've always used for development, and I can't install ActiveSync on Vista, but the device isn't recognized in the Mobile Sync Center either. To top it off, when trying to deploy a project for testing, Visual Studio tells me that "Connect to device failed".

How can I pull this off?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've used those units before. The SDK Psion provides the PtxPxa27x: ARMV4I emulation image to aid in deployment/connectivity to their devices.

At any rate, I'd give Psion support a call (if you've got it) and see what they can do about helping you get it connected to Visual Studio on Vista. If you don't have Psion support, I might be able to help you out if you can't find another solution as I've got a line to some Psion support reps that I can poll.

Why can't you install ActiveSync on Vista?

EDIT: Nevermind, I just looked it up. Mobile Sync Centre manages this... duh. :)

Doing a little research quickly I see [this](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsmobile/en-us/help/synchronize/device-center.mspx):

*Enables you to set up new partnerships, synchronize content and manage music, pictures and video with Windows Mobile powered devices (Windows Mobile 2003 or later).*

*For Windows Embedded CE 4.2, 5.0, Pocket PC 2002, and Smartphone 2002 devices, basic connectivity support includes connecting over USB and serial, using desktop passthrough with the PC’s Internet connection, and file browse.*

Sounds to me like if you're on CE 4.2/5.0 that it might be a Psion ROM issue. Found a number of links with some [suggestions](http://www.pocketpcfaq.com/faqs/wmdc/t-shoot-wmdc.htm).